# ModelState.IsValid even when it should not be?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have API where I need to validate my user model. I choose an approach where I create different classes for Create/Edit actions to avoid mass-assignment and divide validation and actual model apart.

I don't know why but `ModelState.IsValid` returns true even when it should not. Am I doing something wrong?

## Controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(UserCreate user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) // It's valid even when user = null
    {
        var newUser = new User
        {
            Username = user.Username,
            Password = user.Password,
            Name = user.Name
        };
        _db.Users.Add(newUser);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, new { newUser.Id, newUser.Username, newUser.Name });
    }
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}
```

## Model

```
public class UserCreate
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

## Debug proof

[image: proof]

Comment: Be sure that the Html Input names you have provided in your view should match your model properties. i.e. names of the input element on view should be "Username", "Password", "Name". it could be the reason that your user object is null which resulted into ModelState.IsValid

Comment: @KD It's not using HTML, it's expecting JSON since it's API, not a website. But yea, I get your point - even if I send empty JSON object it will work.

Comment: Hi @Steve : Can you show the View ?

Comment: @PKKG There is no view, it's API. Anyway the problem occurs when I send nothing. I need to send at-minimum empty json object.

Comment: You need to put [Required] before UserCreate

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The `ModelState.IsValid` internally checks the `Values.All(modelState => modelState.Errors.Count == 0)` expression.

Because there was no input the `Values` collection will be empty so `ModelState.IsValid` will be `true`.

So you need to explicitly handle this case with:

```
if (user != null && ModelState.IsValid)
{

}
```

Whether this is a good or bad design decision that if you validate nothing it will true is a different question...

Comment: But how can I avoid it then? I thought cases like these are built-in by default. Indeed, when I send empty JSON object it shows errors. Very strange..

Comment: I don't think that the framework should handle this case for you, because this is valid scenario that a parameter is `null`. You can create an actionfilter for example that handles that the parameter cannot be `null`...

Comment: I will just implement some global filter that will check if it's valid and it's null so I won't even have to write that in my controllers. Thanks for answer!

Comment: @Steve: By any chance, did you manage to write a `filter` that could check if the model is null as well as a valid one ?

Comment: @nemesv I'm not sure I agree with you.  You're asking for a specific model and if you get null in place of that model, it's NOT the model. So, how could the model be valid if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Throwing badrequest(modelstate) from within this "if" will result in the error: "the modelstate is valid"..    which is a very message for an error imho

Comment: @nemesv  where can I get the isValid method imeplementation code. how do you know isValid internally check Values.All(modelState => modelState.Errors.Count == 0) expression.

Comment: @MannanBahelim ASP.NET MVC/Web.api is open source, you can find the source code on github: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack  to code is in the question can be found here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/ModelBinding/ModelStateDictionary.cs

Answer (score 27):

Here is an action filter to check for null models or invalid models. (so you dont have to write the check on every action)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace Studio.Lms.TrackingServices.Filters
{
    public class ValidateViewModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ActionArguments.Any(kv => kv.Value == null)) {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Arguments cannot be null");
            }

            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false) {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can register it globally:

```
config.Filters.Add(new ValidateViewModelAttribute());
```

Or use it on demand on classes/actions

```
 [ValidateViewModel]
 public class UsersController : ApiController
 { ...
```

Comment: This returns Bad Request if the action has optional parameters, for example `Get(string id, string something = null)`.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote a custom filter which not only ensures that all non optional object properties are passed, but also checks if model state is valid:

```
[AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<HttpActionDescriptor, IList<string>> NotNullParameterNames =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<HttpActionDescriptor, IList<string>> ();


    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs before the action method is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext">The action context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting (HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var not_null_parameter_names = GetNotNullParameterNames (actionContext);
        foreach (var not_null_parameter_name in not_null_parameter_names)
        {
            object value;
            if (!actionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue (not_null_parameter_name, out value) || value == null)
                actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError (not_null_parameter_name, "Parameter \"" + not_null_parameter_name + "\" was not specified.");
        }


        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse (HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
    }


    private static IList<string> GetNotNullParameterNames (HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var result = NotNullParameterNames.GetOrAdd (actionContext.ActionDescriptor,
                                                     descriptor => descriptor.GetParameters ()
                                                                             .Where (p => !p.IsOptional && p.DefaultValue == null &&
                                                                                          !p.ParameterType.IsValueType &&
                                                                                          p.ParameterType != typeof (string))
                                                                             .Select (p => p.ParameterName)
                                                                             .ToList ());

        return result;
    }
}
```

And I put it in global filter for all Web API actions:

```
config.Filters.Add (new ValidateModelAttribute ());
```

Comment: This does Not display model error when an object's required property is missing. I debugged the GetNotNullParameterNames and it only returns the model itself and checks if it's null. It doesn't look at individual model members.

Comment: @tunafish24 If the model is null, I don't think it makes sense to return individual model validation errors. If the model has a value, but some of it's members are invalid, the above filter will correctly return the invalid errors.

Answer (score 5):

Updated slightly for asp.net core...

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class CheckRequiredModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var requiredParameters = context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.Where(
            p => ((ControllerParameterDescriptor)p).ParameterInfo.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredModelAttribute>() != null).Select(p => p.Name);

        foreach (var argument in context.ActionArguments.Where(a => requiredParameters.Contains(a.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)))
        {
            if (argument.Value == null)
            {
                context.ModelState.AddModelError(argument.Key, $"The argument '{argument.Key}' cannot be null.");
            }
        }

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public sealed class RequiredModelAttribute : Attribute
{
}

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(CheckRequiredModelAttribute));
});

public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromBody][RequiredModel]RequestModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me, and in my case, I had to change `using Microsoft.Build.Framework;` to `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` (and add the reference).

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution to this problem and came out here first. After some further research I have realized the following solution:

How do you use my solution?
You can register it globally:

```
config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateAttribute());
```

Or use it on demand for a class

```
[ValidateModelState]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{...
```

or for a methode

```
[ValidateModelState]
public IHttpActionResult Create([Required] UserModel data)
{...
```

As you can see, a `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]` atribute has been placed in the method parameter.
This indicates that the model is required and can not be `null`.

You can also use with a custom message:

```
[ValidateModelState]
public IHttpActionResult Create([Required(ErrorMessage = "Custom message")] UserModel data)
{...
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace your_base_namespace.Web.Http.Filters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
    public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private delegate void ValidateHandler(HttpActionContext actionContext);

        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<HttpActionBinding, ValidateHandler> _validateActionByActionBinding;

        static ValidateModelStateAttribute()
        {
            _validateActionByActionBinding = new ConcurrentDictionary<HttpActionBinding, ValidateHandler>();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            GetValidateHandler(actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding)(actionContext);

            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
                return;

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }

        private ValidateHandler GetValidateHandler(HttpActionBinding actionBinding)
        {
            ValidateHandler validateAction;

            if (!_validateActionByActionBinding.TryGetValue(actionBinding, out validateAction))
                _validateActionByActionBinding.TryAdd(actionBinding, validateAction = CreateValidateHandler(actionBinding));

            return validateAction;
        }

        private ValidateHandler CreateValidateHandler(HttpActionBinding actionBinding)
        {
            ValidateHandler handler = new ValidateHandler(c => { });

            var parameters = actionBinding.ParameterBindings;

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                var parameterDescriptor = (ReflectedHttpParameterDescriptor)parameters[i].Descriptor;
                var attribute = parameterDescriptor.ParameterInfo.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>(true);

                if (attribute != null)
                    handler += CreateValidateHandler(attribute, parameterDescriptor.ParameterName);
            }

            return handler;
        }

        private static ValidateHandler CreateValidateHandler(ValidationAttribute attribute, string name)
        {            
            return CreateValidateHandler(attribute, new ValidationContext(new object()) { MemberName = name });
        }

        private static ValidateHandler CreateValidateHandler(ValidationAttribute attribute, ValidationContext context)
        {
            return new ValidateHandler(actionContext =>
            {
                object value;
                actionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue(context.MemberName, out value);

                var validationResult = attribute.GetValidationResult(value, context);
                if (validationResult != null)
                    actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError(context.MemberName, validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For my case which is, avoiding null payload as valid modelstate, I changed a bit. RequiredAttribute turned into FromBodyAttribute, then in your last method, I'm just checking if 'value' is null. works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple Solution for your problem

```
public class UserCreate
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Here **AllowEmptyStrings = false** can be used for your validation

Comment: Can also add minimum string length, and other validations.

Comment: Yes, that can be done, also we can create a custom filters if required, like for INT to have values greater than 0

Comment: The default behavior for the `Required` attribute is that empty strings are considered invalid. See [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings?view=net-7.0). Using `AllowEmptyString = false` is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

in the `startup.cs` file's `ConfigureServices()`

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to create an `Attribute` along with an `ActionFilter` and a `Extension Method` to avoid null models.

The extension method looks for parameters with the `NotNull` attribute and check if they are null, if true, they are instantiated and set in the `ActionArguments` property.

This solution can be found here: https://gist.github.com/arielmoraes/63a39a758026b47483c405b77c3e96b9

Answer (score 0):

This "ModelState.IsValid returns true even when it should not" problem can also appear if you forgot to add getters and setters on your model (OP didn't forget, but I did which led me to this question). I hope it's ok to provide solutions that have the same symptoms but are slightly different than OP's code:

Wrong:

```
    public class UserRegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Login; // WRONG
        [Required]
        public string Password; // WRONG
    }
```

Good:

```cs
    public class UserRegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Login { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

this issue happened to me .i do not know why but take it easy just change your action Object name(UserCreate User) by some other like (UserCreate User_create)