# Does ModelState.IsValid=true guarantee that the passed model parameter is not null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Assume that we have `Create` and `Edit` action methods that are attributed by `HttpPost` and they have a `model` parameter of type, for example, `BlogViewModel` as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(..., BlogViewModel model)
{
....
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(..., BlogViewModel model)
{
....
}
```

In their body, we usually do validation as follows.

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
// do something 
}
```

Here, `do something` can be an operation accessing a property of the `model`.

## Question

I am not sure whether or not there is a possibility in which `model` becomes `null`. If `model` is `null` then `do something` (such as accessing a property of `model`) will throw an exception.

I read many examples (from the internet and textbooks), I have not seen someone doing double check as follows yet.

```
if(model!=null)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    // do something
    }
}
```

or

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if(model!=null)
    {
    // do something
    }
}
```

Probably, the condition `ModelState.IsValid` is `true` guarantees that `model` is not `null`.

Is my assumption here correct? I am afraid I am doing a time-bomb assumption.

Comment: The model will only be `null` if there are other errors with you code

Comment: @StephenMuecke: So is it necessary to always do double check as shown in my code above? Or `ModelState.IsValid=true` does not guarantee that `model != null`?

Comment: It's generally be a good idea to check for `null` anyway. Hypothetically, it shouldn't be `null`, all going well but a refactor or other misconfiguration (e.g., routing), could cause it to be `null`.

Comment: Actually, ModelState.IsValid checks if any errors is added to the ModelState, so in the case where model is nullable, ModelState is valid even if model is null. In your case however, BlogViewModel is required in your post request, so a request with a null model will raise exception instead. Therefore, you do not need to check if model is null in this case.

Comment: `ModelState` is valid of the model is `null` (its only invalid if the `ModelBinder` attempts to set the value of property which is not valid). The model will be `null` if no values are passed in the request which match a model property name, or if you name the parameter the same as one of the properties in the model.

Comment: Personally I don't think its necessary (and have never seen any example of it). In the 2nd case above, you will have corrected that before publishing, and if no values matching your model properties were sent in the request, you can assume its a malicious user and so what if they see the error page that will result from the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, no, ModelState.IsValid does not check if your model is null and will throw an error if that happens.

In an API it is quite easy to have null models, if you make a mistake while building your request model and it doesn't match what the endpoint expects.

Or someone else could look at your website, see the API calls and decides to have some fun and flood your API with requests which don't have valid models.

There are ways to check for null models in one place such as here : [ModelState is valid with null model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851352/modelstate-is-valid-with-null-model)

Answer (score 1):

what is Model State ?
The ModelState represents a collection of name and value pairs that were submitted to the server during a POST

What's in a ModelState?
Here's what those values look like, from the same debugger session:
[image]
Each of the properties has an instance of ValueProviderResult that contains the actual values submitted to the server.

Validation errors in Model State...
eg:-

```
[Required]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Last Name must be less than {1} characters.")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

in this case if your LastName contain more than 50 caracters, ModelState if false, because vaueProvidedResult having exception

Hope you got the understating about ModelState

Answer for your question is you can handle model from modelState

if model null automatically modelState is not valid

Comment: OP did not ask what `ModelState` is!

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes answer for whole question he needs to understand you can handle model from modelState

Comment: _if model null automatically modelState is not valid_ is wrong

Comment: @StephenMuecke is it possible on theory? sry i never faced that situation

Comment: If nothing is sent in the request that matches a model property, then the model will not be initialized by the `DefaultModelBinder` and therefore nothing is added to `ModelState` and it will be valid.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok thanks for the update, i will look more

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply no.

[`ModelState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx) represents attempts to bind a posted form (marked with `BeginForm`) to an action method which also includes validation information. It carries default model binder settings that specify which validation settings should be included to viewmodel, e.g. `RequiredAttribute`, so that null-value checking for required fields depend on which validation settings exist, not in `ModelStateDictionary` itself.

When the form is submitted, the `DefaultModelBinder` sets up viewmodel binding and checks every properties inside bound viewmodel class for presence of validation settings (i.e. attributes). If submitted values doesn't match with criteria being set (e.g. `null`/empty value in properties marked with `RequiredAttribute`), it will add validation error(s) to [`ModelState.Errors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.errors(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ModelState.Errors) property, and subsequently [`ModelStateDictionary.IsValid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.isvalid(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.IsValid) returns false because it depends on `Errors` property count. Here is `IsValid` checking mechanism taken from [ModelStateDictionary source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ModelStateDictionary.cs):

```
public class ModelStateDictionary : IDictionary<string, ModelState>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, ModelState> _innerDictionary;

    public ICollection<ModelState> Values
    {
        get { return _innerDictionary.Values; }
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return Values.All(modelState => modelState.Errors.Count == 0); 
    }
}
```

Hence, if all model properties set to null/empty without specifying `RequiredAttribute`, the `ModelStateDictionary.IsValid` value still being `true` due to no validation attributes present & the model binding works.

Similar issue:

[ModelState.IsValid even when it should not be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923622/modelstate-isvalid-even-when-it-should-not-be)