# Validate empty or null inputs on web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

we can validate mandatory fields by using Required attribute but what about model what if we pass empty post body ? i have check the controller i am getting null object and `ModelState.IsValid` is true on action executing even though there are required fields in model. is there any way to validate null/empty body ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851352/modelstate-is-valid-with-null-model

Answer (score 1):

You can as well check explicitly

```
if (inputModel == null) {
return BadRequest();
}
```