# ModelSate.IsValid returns true when posting to Web Api action and resulting Model is null

Tags: c#, model-binding, asp.net-web-api2

Using Chrome PostMan, I noticed that if I post to an action method without passing any form parameters the `ModelState.IsValid` returns true even if I have `[Required]` validation attribute set on the model properties.

The weird thing is that the `Model` passed as a parameter has a value of `null` even though `IsValid` is `true`.

Is there a way to intercept the `Model` from `OnActionExecuting` to check if the Model is null and handle the situation appropriately or is there a better way to ensure `IsValid` returns `false` in this case?

Comment: Can you provide your model and API code?  If you have an `RequiredAttribute` and the value is `null`, validation should return `false`.  Unless it is a non-nullable data type.  This would cause it to default to a value, eg `int` defaults to `0` so it is technically valid data.  See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCbt9v)

Comment: Question itself and @Doug Dawson answer are full duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923622/modelstate-isvalid-even-when-it-should-not-be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your model data it will be impossible to truly help you.

However, your issue stems from the following:

- `ModelState.IsValid` : When this is invoked, it will perform the following in essence: `Values.All(m => m.Errors.Count == 0)`.  Since the collection is empty, it will still validate as `true`.  Since the collection is absent of errors.

To properly account for the information, you'll need to do the following:

```
// If Invalid
if(model == null && !ModelState.IsValid)
     return View("Error");

// If Vaild
if(model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
     return View("Valid");
```

> The `ModelState.IsValid` represents the state of an attempt to bind a
>   posted form to an *action method*, which includes the validation
>   information.  Another potential approach would be to do a `Count` on
>   the `KeyValuePair` within the `Dictionary`.

```
if(ModelState.Count != 0)
     return View("Valid");
```

Another suggestion, hopefully this clarifies.  The `IsValid` will trigger its count based on potential errors.  If non exist within the *Collection* it will always return `true`.

Documentation:

- [Microsoft Developer Network MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.count(v=vs.118).aspx).
- [Brad Wilson's Answer, Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881281/what-is-modelstate-isvalid-valid-for-in-asp-net-mvc-in-nerddinner).
- [Nemesv's Answer, Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923622/modelstate-isvalid-even-when-it-should-not-be).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The closest I could find to "official" insight into this was a post at ASP.NET. The code shown in their example tests the model for null first and then checks if the model is valid in a separate step.

[ASP.NET Model Binding](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-model-binding)

This is answered in the link below. Here's some of the content from that post:

The ModelState.IsValid internally checks the Values.All(modelState => modelState.Errors.Count == 0) expression.

Because there was no input the Values collection will be empty so ModelState.IsValid will be true.

So you need to explicitly handle this case with:

```
if (user != null && ModelState.IsValid)
{

}
```

[Source Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923622/modelstate-isvalid-even-when-it-should-not-be)